# package com.google.gson.internal.bind.util is declared in module com.google.gson, which does not export it

Tags: java, gson, openapi-generator, java-module

I got this error message when compiling code generated from the OpenAPI generator:

```
package com.google.gson.internal.bind.util is declared in module com.google.gson, which does not export it
```

In my build.gradle I used this dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'
```

and in my module-info.java I included:

```
requires com.google.gson;
```

Answer (score 0):

In build.gradle include "--add-exports $MODULE/$PACKAGE=$READING_MODULE":

```
compileJava {
doFirst {
    options.compilerArgs = [
            '--module-path', classpath.asPath,                
            '--add-exports', 'com.google.gson/com.google.gson.internal.bind.util=MyModule' // resolves "package com.google.gson.internal.bind.util is declared in module com.google.gson, which does not export it" 
    ]
    classpath = files()                                            
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

While adding compiler options to allow access to this package solves the error, the question is rather why you rely on internal Gson packages in the first place, and if there are official alternatives to this.

Based on the package name it sounds like you are using Gson's internal `ISO8601Utils` class. A better alternative to this would be to use the classes from the [`java.time` package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) or the [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for formatting and parsing dates.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful and instructive comments. I totally agree. Sorry I failed to include that I didn't write the code that used Gson internal but it was generated by the OpenAPI generator and so I was trying to correct a compile error with this code - working with what I was given. Perhaps there's an option in the OpenAPI config that prevents Gson being used but I haven't seen this yet. By posting this error and solution I was trying to help other OpenAPI user's.

Comment: Looks like there is an existing [openapi-generator issue](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/3420) for this, but it is currently still unresolved. Maybe you can work around this by choosing a different `serializationLibrary`, see the [Java generator config options](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/java#config-options). Not sure if this could cause any behavior change.